# can iPhone 51. simulator work as iphone 4s

Tags: bluetooth

I am relatively new to iOS. I am working developing an app using CoreBluetooth conmunicating with a BLE device. but I failed to test my app on iphone simulator on Mac mini.

My Mac mini has OS Lion,and it has bluetooth4.0.but in iPhone simulator, I cannot open Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator isn't exactly what i would call a good tool since it misses many components of the real device and its behaviour (especially the UI) is way too buggy to give reliable informations.

As for the BT: It could be that your Bluetooth is already used by the OS, so one thing you can try is

> $ sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="never"

and reboot.